# DoS attack in my home router's logs

Tags: attacks, router, denial-of-service

I logged in to my router to try to figure out why my phone randomly keeps being unable to connect to my WiFi. I looked in the logs and saw 2 strange rows:

```
[DoS attack: IP packet w/MC or BC SRC addr] from [some IP address], port 0
[DoS attack: Teardrop or derivative] from [some other IP address], port 41813
```

Should I be worried? What are these rows saying?

Comment: Just 1 of each? that's not an issue. And DoS attacks won't affect your internal network's WiFi.

Comment: @schroeder these were the first ones I found without scrolling down the logs too much. These didn't happen too close to each other either.

Comment: Right, so there's not much to be worried about. I also just googled these lines and they are very common messages.